# multilingual blocks in drupal6

Tags: i18n-l10n, blocks

I use drupal 6 . I have some menus in the site. I 'm going to add other language support to my website. I know how to create multilingual content (nodes) but I don't know how to do it with menus like navigation menus.

would you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) suite of modules, you can enable the Internationalization blocks module (called Translate Blocks).

This will allow you to assign a language (or languages) to each block.

This way, you can create a menu for each language and then assign a language to each menu block.

- Note that there is also a Translate Menu module in the Internationalization suite.  This module allows you to create one menu with items of multiple languages.  However, this can get confusing and complicated very fast and is often difficult to maintain over time.  For this reason, most people create separate menus for each language as described above.